# Member, class, accessibility clarification

Tags: java

Here is an example that I can't understand:

```
abstract class Personne { 
    protected static int nbPersonnes=0;

    static void nbpersonnes (){
    System.out.println(
    “\n Nombre d’employés :“ + nbPersonnes +
    “\n Nombre de secretaires  : “ + Secretaire.nbSecretaire() +

    }
```

The second class is `Secretaire`:

```
class Secretaire extends Personne {        
       private String numBureau;
       private static int nbSecretaires; 
       Secretaire (String nom, String prenom, String rue,String ville,String numBureau) {
          super(nom,prenom,rue,ville);
          this.numBureau=numBureau;
          nbSecretaires++;}
```

How can the class `Personne` access private member ***`Secretaire.nbSecretaire()`***?

I thought the class `Secretaire` can access `Personne` members, and not the opposite? `nbSecretaires` is a private member. How can it be accessed outside the class?

Comment: Your question would be *much* easier to understand if you indented the code more readably.

Comment: Please rephrase and reformat your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Secretaire.nbSecretaire()` is a *static method invocation expression*. It does not access the private `nbSecretaire` member, but the method `nbSecretaire()`, whose definition you did not show.

However, if your `Secretaire` class is nested within `Personne`, then all its members, even private ones, will be accessible from `Personne`.

NOTE: As of the time of my answer, the syntax of your posted code is too mangled to be clear whether this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

> i thought class Secretaire can access Personne'members, and not the opposite ?

That would be true in C#, but not in Java.

In Java, all the code within the same top-level class can access all the private members of all the classes declared within that top-level class (including the top-level class itself).

From [JLS 6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.